# Updating Django project from sqlite to Postgres: No manage.py specified, ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: django, postgresql

On my first Django project, I got started with a sqlite database, and now I'm switching to Postgres. The first part of the code that I wrote and tested was an import management command, to read records in from a file and create database records for them, and that's been working great. So to start making the change, I've updated the default database info in settings.py, and I ran migrations for it like so:

```
python3 manage.py migrate --database=default
```

I can see the correct table structure when I view the new database in pgAdmin 4 (just with no rows populated yet)- and the field max values appear to all match what's in the model- hooray! I also added some code to get the ENV_ROLE and database password from environment variables, as recommended here: https://ultimatedjango.com/learn-django/lessons/handling-sensitive-keys/

Next I run my import management command, and **the problem**: I can run this successfully from the terminal, but when I try running it from within PyCharm I'm getting errors I never saw while running it using the sqlite database:

```
    No manage.py file specified in Settings->Django Support
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/django-admin.py importgedcom Test_tree.ged
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
    app_name = commands[subcommand]
KeyError: 'importgedcom'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 231, in fetch_command
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.settings'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I see a few interesting bits in there, likely multiple/different issues in my setup running from PyCharm vs from the terminal:

- `No manage.py file specified in Settings->Django Support`. My configuration for the management command has always included this: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings;` I did make one update to the configuration, just to add `ENV_ROLE=development`
- `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.settings'`. I didn't rename the project or app, only updated settings.py (default database and environment logic)

UPDATE: I *can* run this to completion while stepping through in debug mode, I only see the error when I hit PyCharm's green play button to run it.

These errors happen before the code even does anything (I don't make it to print statements in the add_arguments or handle methods), so there's some problem with the setup. Any advice on what to check/do next, or is there more info I can give that would help figure out next steps?

Comment: Can your post the output of your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable?

Comment: So this `importgedcom` command reads data from a file and creates objects in the db? To help in debugging, you can insert some `print` statements in your code to print the values that you're passing to the db **before** creating the object. When the command fails again, it will be much easier to identify which values are longer than expected.

Comment: Thank you both! Yes I had two different issues: running from the terminal was all about field lengths, fixed now, but there's a separate setup issue when running from inside PyCharm- will update the description above now to reflect that

Comment: Joe you're onto something- when I echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, it appears to be empty (though the whole time I've had it in there set to mysite.settings)